# Docker network affecting host network on container restart : ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED in chrome

Tags: docker, google-chrome, networking, docker-compose, docker-network

I am facing a weird issue with the **docker networks**. I am using an external bridge network named **extenal_network** in my docker containers with **auto-restart** enabled. I am not able to access my host network if any of the containers is restarting due to some error, maybe code or infra related.

Please refer attached screenshot for more clarity.

[image: Network error]

> **I've tried the below links but no luck.**

- https://superuser.com/questions/1336567/installing-docker-ce-in-ubuntu-18-04-breaks-internet-connectivity-of-host
- https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-influence-which-network-address-ranges-docker-chooses-during-a-docker-network-create
- https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-access-internet-after-installing-docker-in-a-fresh-ubuntu-18-04-machine/53416
- https://superuser.com/questions/747735/regularly-getting-err-network-changed-errors-in-chrome/773971

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10.20.1-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python make g++
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
```

**Docker-Compose**

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: 'network_poc:latest'
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 2G
    networks:
      - extenal_network
    restart: always
    command: node index.js

networks:
  shared_network:
    external:
      name: extenal_network
```

> **docker inspect extenal_network**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "extenal_network",
        "Id": "96476c227ddc14aa23d376392d380b2674fcbad109c90e7436c0cddd5c0a9ac5",
        "Created": "2020-04-14T00:17:10.89980675+05:30",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "7621a2b5a7e460a905bf86c427aea38b6374ac621c0c1a2b9eca4b671aea4dfe": {
                "Name": "app",
                "EndpointID": "04e9d14a17af05eb7a2b478526365cbce7f726a62f5e2cd315244c2639891b1e",
                "MacAddress": "**:**:**:**:**:**",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciable.

Comment: One more point If I stop the servive that is restarting. The network resume itself.